# Can i use Column widgets within an Expanded widget?

Tags: android, flutter, widget

I am building a post app and I have a post widget then a comments list widget then a textfield. The comments list is a listview.builder and the post widget is just a container. how can i make them both scroll while the textfield remain on the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass **post app(Container)** and **first index Element of comments list** inside a **column** as collective first index inside ListView builder of comment list.

```
   ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {      
              return (index==0) ? Column(children:[Container,first Element]):
                      Other Element for other index}));
```

Comment: yeah but that only takes one child and I have two. i wrapped them in a listview and added a shrink wrap prop to the expanded widget i.e the comment list. and I wrapped this whole thing in an expanded widget and it works. too complicated though.

Comment: I have updated my answer. This can make an easy solution :)

Comment: it's funny i figured out a similiar approach to doing it. but I like yours a bit better. thank you

Comment: Can you accept this answer if it solves your problem?

Comment: I meant accepting answer rather than my comment. You can get idea from here about accepting answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work